# Is this a special/peculiar use of "as interesting as"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, as

I have come across this use of "*as interesting as*" the meaning of which I am not sure about. The context is that I sent emails to several drainlayers explaining a one-off job that I would like to get done and asking if they would be interested to take it. One of them replied he is not interested in this way:

> Thanks for the offer Eugene but I will have to turn down the offer, as
>   interesting as it would be to do.

I have two ideas what that "as interesting as" might mean but not too sure either way:

- althought it would be interesting to do the job you offered, I have
  to decline
- the job is not interesting therefore I have to decline

Can someone please enlighten me on the subject?

Comment: It means that he thinks the job is interesting, but he's declining anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's a *special* use of the expression.  It's just conjugated using the subjunctive -- which is not really necessary but stylistically interesting.

It's built as follows:

> That is interesting to do
>
> That would be interesting to do
>
> As interesting as that would be to do, ... (I can't do it)